# VS Code terraform extension error :Couldn't start client Language Serve

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform

Couldn't start client Language Server: Terraform VS code extension error. Syntax are not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `terraform init` so that the language server knows which schema to use. The extension itself doesn't seem to tell you this, but it's in the [directions from HashiCorp](https://github.com/hashicorp/vscode-terraform#getting-started).